# Getting different diagnostic result with flutter doctor command

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, flutter, command-prompt

I have started my first project with Flutter. I have reviewed some flutter documentation as well as checked some examples.

I have created one sample project and while I am going to run this project then Android Studio showing `<no devices>`.

So I tried `flutter doctor` command in Android Studio Terminal, then I see one error about Android SDK "Unable to locate Android SDK".

Then I tried the same command in Command Prompt. Here I am getting all the setup is OK.

See attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Try completely exiting Android Studio and opening it again. It may have an old path cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research in the google and Stackoverflow, i found the solution.

I go through two flow

1. Invalidate Cache and Restart
2. Executed `flutter update` command.

After successfully update, everything started working fine.